# Masm32 run a function at specific second or minute

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, masm32

Is there any way in masm32 to run a function(proc) **at every specific second or minute or hour**?

I know Windows has a command `schtasks` to create scheduled task. So I believe there must be some way to do the job.

Comment: You mean *run* a function?  "commit" is not something you do to a function.  I think you may have mis-translated something from another language; "commit an act of bravery" is a valid phrase, where "commit" means "perform", but it's never used that way in computing.  In computing, "commit" is used in the sense of "make a transaction permanent", or "resources committed to something".  We just say "run" or "execute" for making code run.

Comment: Do you want to have your program sit there and keep checking the clock to see if it's time to run?  Or do you want Windows to run your program at the proper time?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd :I want to set up a timer.It execute my code at the time I scheduled.
like when I am in dos,8086 assmebly,I can use the bios clock interrupt 251CH to determine the code every time program perform.I check second and minute in my code,so I do job at specific second or minute

Comment: use [`SetWaitableTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setwaitabletimer) for this or wait via `ZwDelayExecution` for example. compiler or language here not related at all

Comment: And note whatever you do it will  only be window's best effort, it will wait at least as long as specified but if the machine is busy there may be further delay. Although if you are already waiting minutes then some (usually) slight delay will hardly matter.

Comment: If you allow a slight delay, you could simply use the [`Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) function in a new thread: `while (true) {Sleep (Milliseconds); proc ()}` .